# Handlebars no such file or directory

Tags: node.js, express, handlebars.js

Im trying to load a handlebars file called `login.hbs` but I keep getting an error: `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open '/Users/admin/Documents/tc-master/server/views/layout/default-layout.hbs'`

Code and directory structure:

[image: Image with code and directory structure]

Comment: In what folder did you placed this file? It's clear that `app` tries to access the file within `./server/views/....` and not `./views/...`

Comment: @Variable views/login.hbs

Comment: Try this: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/../views'));` or move `./views` to `./server`

Comment: @Variable when I `console.log(__dirname);` it outputs `/Users/admin/Documents/tc-master/server` instead of `/Users/admin/Documents/tc-master`

Comment: That's because `__dirname` reflects the current directory where this javascript file is located and executed ^^. Your code expects the `views` folder to be located in `./server/...`

Comment: How can I access the `./views` folder without moving it into the `./server` folder

Comment: Try this: `app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, '/../views'));`

Answer (score 20):

In the above example from the course, Max does not use any layout in the beginning and the default value for the engine initialization makes the 
*extname*  as  **.handlebars** 
*defaultLayout* as **main-layout** as the 
*layoutsDir* as **view/layouts**.

we have to initialize this with blank values in the beginning as below if we don't have any layout defined yet,

```
app.engine(
   'hbs',
   expressHbs({
      extname: "hbs",
      defaultLayout: "",
      layoutsDir: "",
   })
);
```

Comment: Good call! I assume you're talking about Maximilian Schwarzmüller's NodeJS Complete Course.

Comment: @AndreiV I'm taking Max's Node.js course right now and just hit the same issue.